# share custom photo album images

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiimagepickercontroller, sharekit, social-framework

I created custom photo album for capturing photos. And i invoked this album inside my app. After clicking button the album is invoked. But i can't share this image to facebook. I used socialframework for sharing.

code:

```
photopick= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [photopick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

    [photopick setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 50)];

    [photopick addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlbum:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:photopick];

-(void)showAlbum:(id)sender{

    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

   // imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;


    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    //release picker
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    //set image

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];




    //  newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [newImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

    //  [newImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];



    [self.view addSubview:newImage];

    // [newImage release];


    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

After picking image i have other button to share newImage (album image) to facebook:

```
-(void)share:(id)sender{

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            [controller setInitialText:@"My Home Decoration"];
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
        }
}
```

But how can i set album image to inside SLComposeViewController. Some docs mentioned used `UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"` Here i don't have imageName. I have images from album

Comment: you can add image in SLComposeViewController [controller addImage:newImage.image];

Comment: what is image? is it UIImage *image;

Comment: yes..UIImage. add imageView.image